# dynamic column headers in a sorted table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to loop through an array in order to print some column headers dynamically. I see that the array values are inserted into the HTML code, but I'm unable to sort my table whenever I click on one of the column headers.

Strange thing is: when I replace the {{ colHeader }} variable with plaintext html the tablesorter is functioning normally. So does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $scope.colHeaders =  {
        'id' ,
        'name' ,
        'symbol',
    };
    $scope.sortType    = 'id'; // specifies column to sort

</script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="colHeader in colHeaders">
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = '{{ colHeader }}'">
                column header
            </a>
          </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline functions in html templates is a bad idea.

Try using a function from your controller like this: `<th ng-repeat="colHeader in colHeaders" ng-click="sortBy(colHeader)">`

Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/NTgjVpKoKhrjyP1YuN2n